# Parsing Multiple JSON Objects into a CSV using Ruby

Tags: json, ruby, csv, parsing, object

I'm currently working with a .txt file that contains multiple JSON objects from an API call. I'm looking for a way to parse all these objects into a .csv file. In the past, I've been able to get one JSON object into a .csv, but I am unsure how to do it for multiple.

Sample JSON:

```
[{"field1":["value1"], "field2": ["value2"]}]
[{"field1":["value1"], "field2": ["value2"]}]
[{"field1":["value1"], "field2": ["value2"]}]
```

The code I'm currently using to push JSON into a CSV is below, although it seems to only work on one JSON object. What I believe I need is some kind of loop that will push each object through, then loop again.

```
require 'csv'
require 'json'

CSV.open("sample.csv", "w") do |csv|
csv << ["field1",
"field2" 
]
  JSON.parse(File.open("json.txt").read).each do |hash| #open json to parse

    csv << hash.values 

   end
end
```

Can anyone give me any suggestions? I've found solutions for multiple object parsing, but none that would really help me with the CSV portion.

Comment: What is the output right now? Seems like you need to unwrap values. Try to do hash.values.flatten, also hash should be an array, so you need to take the value out as well.

Comment: You have a file of multiple JSON documents. If, as in the example data, your file has a single JSON document on each line, then instead of using `read`, use `foreach` and process each line separately. If you are the author of the JSON, then you should fix the output so it generates proper JSON which should be a single array of hashes (encoded in JSON of course). Once you've parsed a line then pass it to CSV as necessary.

Comment: @IvanYouroff as of right now, the code I use can successfully produce a CSV file from one JSON object.

Comment: @theTinMan thank you, I'll try using that solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'csv'
require 'json'

CSV.open("sample.csv", "w") do |csv|
  csv << ["field1", "field2"]
  File.open("json.txt").each do |line|
    csv << JSON.parse(line).first.values.flatten
   end
end
```

Though this is not really safe considering format changes, so I would add some validation